# How can I add to list only once in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, spyder

The code is working and adding to the list. However it is adding to each list three times instead of once. I want to append the items in the list once and not three times.

I have tried to check the range and it is only one. However, it still adds to list with the append method three times

```
newlist= [['ï»¿id', 'name', 'lastContactedTime', 'email', 'phone_phones', 'home_phones', 'mobile_phones', 'work_phones', 'fax_phones', 'other_phones', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'address_3', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'country', 'tags'], ['12-contacts', 'Courtney James', '', 'courtney@forlanchema.com', '+1 3455463849', '', '', '', '', '', '654 Rodney Franklin street', '', '', 'Birmingham', 'AL', '45678', 'US', ''], ['4-contacts', 'Joe Malcoun', '2019-08-13 14:41:12', 'ceo@nutshell.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '212 South Fifth Ave', '', '', 'Ann Arbor', 'MI', '48103', 'US', ''], ['8-contacts', 'Rafael Acosta', '', 'racosta@forlanchema.com', '+1 338551534', '', '', '', '', '', '13 Jordan Avenue SW', '', '', 'Birmingham', 'AL', '45302', 'US', '']]
namelist = [] # new, empty list
for i in range(1, len(newlist)):
    names = newlist[i][1].split() # this yields [first_name, last_name]
    namelist.append([names[1], names[0]]) # [last_name, first_name]
companylist=[]
for i in range(1, len(newlist)):
    p = re.compile(r'(.+)@(.+)\.(.+)')
    test_str = newlist[i][3]
    company= re.findall(p, test_str)
    companyname= list(company[0][1])
    companynom=''.join(companyname)
    companylist.append(companynom) #yields company names
    # strip non-numeric characters'
    workphone = []
    wrkstreetaddress = []
    workcityaddress = []
    wrkstate = []
    wrkzip = []

for i in range(1, len(newlist)):
     phone = re.sub(r'\D', '', newlist[i][4])
 # remove leading 1 (area codes never start with 1)
     phone = phone.lstrip('1')
     workingphone= '{}.{}.{}'.format(phone[0:3], phone[3:6], phone[6:])
     workphone.append(workingphone) #yields a list of workphone numbers
     wrkstraddress= newlist[i][10]
     wrkstreetaddress.append(wrkstraddress) #yields a list of work street addresses
     wrkcityaddress= newlist[i][13] #yields a list of city addresses
     workcityaddress.append(wrkcityaddress)
     workstate= newlist[i][14] #yields a list of states
     wrkstate.append(workstate)
     workzip=newlist[i][15]
     wrkzip.append(workzip) #yields a list of zip codes
```

I expect each list to contain one list with three items:

If I print workstreetaddress list I get:

```
print(wrskstreetaddress)

['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave', '13 Jordan Avenue SW']
instead of:
['654 Rodney Franklin street']
['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave']
['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave', '13 Jordan Avenue SW']
```

The same for all the other lists from companylist to wrkzip I get the same results with adding the items three times instead of once

Comment: Which list are you talking about, there are many lists in your code ;) Are you sure about the indentation of the last loop (i.e. inside the second loop)?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? You mention having difficulty with "**The List**", but make no mention as to which list you are referring. Also, this code is longer then you need to reproduce this issue (I predict you could do it in 3 lines).  Please try to remove unnecessary code and create a minimal complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am voting to close this question, as it is unclear what you are asking and you have not responded to attempts to gain more information.

Comment: I have added the list

Comment: Does the indentation as posted match the indentation in your code? It doesn't really make sense as is.

Comment: I have removed the indentation and I am still getting the same results

Comment: When I run your posted code, `print(wrkstreetaddress)` prints `['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave', '13 Jordan Avenue SW']`. You haven't provided enough information for others to get your results.

Comment: I guess it is something wrong with Spyder, my IDE. I appended the list to a new list and got one list. Sorry for not making myself clear at first and thanks everyone for their patience and help

Comment: I suspect that you have `print(wrkstreetaddress)` in the body of the last loop, rather than after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of this print statement at the end of your code:

```
print(workphone, wrkstreetaddress, workcityaddress, wrkstate, wrkzip)
```

Yields:

```
['345.546.3849', '..', '338.551.534'] ['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave', '13 Jordan Avenue SW'] ['Birmingham', 'Ann Arbor', 'Birmingham'] ['AL', 'MI', 'AL'] ['45678', '48103', '45302']
```

I don't see a problem with your lists.

Answer (score 1):

### Everything is better with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist[1:], columns=newlist[0])
```

[image]

#### Easily extract individual columns into a list without `for-loops`:

```
addresses = df.address_1.tolist()

print(addresses)

['654 Rodney Franklin street', '212 South Fifth Ave', '13 Jordan Avenue SW']
```

### Easily add or rename `df` columns:

```
# split name into first and last name
df[['first_name', 'last_name']] = df.name.str.split(' ', expand=True)

# rename id
df.rename(columns={'ï»¿id': 'id'}, inplace=True)

# split country_code from phone_phones
df[['country_code', 'phone_phones']] = df.phone_phones.str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

[image]

**Now the data will be easier to work with.**